# JSF with Hibernate sample web application

Tags: hibernate, jsf

Are there any ready-to-use sample web applications using JSF, RichFaces and Hibernate?

Answer (score 10):

Some links from [JSFtutorials.net](http://www.jsftutorials.net/):

- [Use Hibernate and JSF with Less Coding](http://web.archive.org/web/20070406051317/blog.exadel.com/?p=8)
- [A Project Management Web Application based on JavaServer Faces and Hibernate](http://www.cs.umu.se/education/examina/Rapporter/TimoElverkemper.pdf)
- [Easily pass JSF expressions as Hibernate Query Params (no code) by Rick Hightower](http://www.jroller.com/page/RickHigh?entry=integrating_hibernate_and_jsf_so)
- [Pagination using a h:dataGrid and Hibernate by Rick Hightower](http://www.thearcmind.com/confluence/display/SpribernateSF/Pagination+using+a+h_dataGrid+and+Hibernate)
- [Configuring Hibernate, Spring and (MyFaces) JSF by Rick Hightower](http://www.thearcmind.com/confluence/display/SpribernateSF/Configuring+Hibernate%2C+Spring%2C+OpenInSessionViewFilter+and+MyFaces+JSF)
- [Integration of Hibernate and MyFaces](http://wiki.apache.org/myfaces/HibernateAndMyFaces)
- [Creating a Pet Store Application with JavaServer Faces, Spring, and Hibernate by Derek Yang Shen](http://java.sys-con.com/read/46977.htm)
- [Put JSF to work: Build a real-world Web application with JavaServer Faces, the Spring Framework, and Hibernate](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-07-2004/jw-0719-jsf.html)

Answer (score 4):

With [Appfuse](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Home) you can componse one yourself.